# What is the duration of the jquery "slow" value?

Tags: jquery, animation

I was wondering if anyone knows how long jquery actually will animate something when you call something like this:

```
.animate({ marginLeft: '-91px' }, 'slow');
```

Like, what would be equivalent to the `'slow'`? 1000? 1500?

Thanks, I have looked everywhere and can't seem to find it!

Comment: This is actually said in the documentation. [Try to find it](http://api.jquery.com/animate/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Slow is 600 ms

Fast is 200 ms

It can be found in 
http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation on animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/):

Duration:

> Durations are given in milliseconds; higher values indicate slower animations, not faster ones. The default duration is 400 milliseconds. *The strings 'fast' and 'slow' can be supplied to indicate durations of 200 and 600 milliseconds, respectively*.